# How to create a query dynamically for an array of elements?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a basic query as follows

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE (subject_code = '".$subject_code."' )";
```

I have to modify this query to create a query where we have multiple subject codes fetched from an array.

```
$query1="SELECT subject_code FROM subject WHERE (sbranch = '".$branch."' )";
$result = mysqli_query($bmysqli, $query1);
```

Now result holds all the required `subject_codes` say `result[0]=SC1`,`result[1]=SC2` etc....

Now I want to the original query to be modified something as follows

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE (subject_code = SC1 OR subject_code = SC2 .....)";
```

Note that i don't know what are the values of **SC1 SC2 etc**.It depends on the branch and is inside `$result`.

How can i accomplish this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203063/mysql-where-id-is-in-array

Comment: See this  [sql_in](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

Comment: So should i use SELECT * FROM files WHERE subject_code IN ('".$result."')"); Should is use mysql fetch array?

Comment: Check my answer below. I have updated it as result is an associative array.

Comment: okay, I have added a line to typecast object to array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql where id is in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203063/mysql-where-id-is-in-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery like this:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM files 
WHERE subject_code IN (
    SELECT subject_code FROM subject WHERE sbranch = "' . $branch . '"
)';
```

Comment: Wow beautiful answer.

Comment: I dont know how to thank you i was working on this for hours and you provided a simple solution..

Comment: glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Mysql **In** operator
Like this

```
SELECT * FROM files WHERE subject_code in ('SC1','SC2')";
```

You can achieve `('SC1','SC2')` by using **implode** php function,
 like this:

```
$subCodes = implode("','", $subject_array ); 
SELECT * FROM files WHERE subject_code in ('".$subCodes ."')"
```

Comment: But i dont know SC1,SC2 its in $result.How to convert $result to above format?

Answer (score 1):

```
$query1="SELECT subject_code FROM subject WHERE (sbranch = '".$branch."' )";
$result = mysqli_query($bmysqli, $query1);
$codes=(array)$result; //this will convert it in normal array. old school typecasting ;)
$codes=array_values($codes);
$query = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE subject_code in (".implode(",",$codes).")";
//considering result is an object of subject codes.
```

**CODE UPDATED ABOVE** as it is an object.

You don't need to append to the first query. Just build a new query using MySQL in operator and php implode function.

Comment: This is not working because $result is associative array.Can you help me with this..

Comment: Edited the answer. Please mark my answer as correct if it works. Thanks :)

Comment: Error array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

Comment: Out of all the answers this is exactly what i want but still cannot make it to work..

Comment: So when you said that it is an associative array which is not. it is an object. Answer updated again.

Comment: just typecast with (array)

Answer (score 1):

You can use implode  to convert array to string comma delimited

like below:

```
$branch_array = array('subject1', 'subject2', 'subject3');
$branch = implode("','", $subject_array ); 

$query1="SELECT subject_code FROM subject WHERE sbranch  in ('".$branch."')";
```

result:

```
 'subject1', 'subject2', 'subject3'
```

Hope that resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM files WHERE subject_code in ('SC1','SC2')
```

Comment: But i dont know SC1,SC2 its in $result.How to convert $result to above format?

Comment: $ids = join("','",$arrayOfValues);   
$sql = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE subject_code IN ('$ids')";

Answer (score 0):

You can amend your php array to comma delimited string of SubjectCodes.

then:

```
$query1="SELECT * FROM files WHERE subject_code in (".$NewString.") ";
```

$NewString will look something like this:

```
"'SC1', 'SC2', 'SC3'"
```

Comment: The $result array has the subjects but how to convert $result to above format?

Comment: @ElectronicsForKTU
implode( "," , $YourArray)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $result = array(0=>'SC1',1=>'SC2');  //this is your array
 $branch = implode("','", $result );
 $query .= "
   SELECT * FROM files WHERE subject_code in ('".$branch."') "; //this is query
```